Upgrade from 2.4.3-p1 to 2.4.7-p1
I have magento community 2.4.3-p1. i need upgrade to the latest version 2.4.7-p1
use
 composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.7-p1 --no-update   

then
composer update
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires magento/data-migration-tool 2.4.3 -> satisfiable by magento/data-migration-tool[2.4.3].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: monolog/monolog[1.0.0, ..., 1.27.1, 2.0.0, ..., 2.9.3, 3.0.0, ..., 3.7.0].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.7-p1 requires monolog/monolog ^2.7 -> satisfiable by monolog/monolog[2.7.0, ..., 2.9.3].
    - magento/data-migration-tool 2.4.3 requires monolog/monolog ^1.17 -> satisfiable by monolog/monolog[1.17.0, ..., 1.27.1].
    - Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.7-p1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.7-p1].

I will delete data-migration-tool and this error show
Problem 1
- symfony/process[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.10] require php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.3.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
- magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[3.10.0, ..., 3.12.0] require symfony/process ^4.4||^5.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.44, v5.4.0, ..., v5.4.40].
- magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[3.7.0, ..., 3.9.0] require symfony/process ^4.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.44].
- You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: symfony/process[2.0.4, ..., v2.8.52, v3.0.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.0.0, ..., v4.4.44, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.40, v6.0.0, ..., v6.4.8, v7.0.0, ..., v7.1.3].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.4.7-p1 requires symfony/process ^6.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v6.4.0, ..., v6.4.8].
- magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[3.0.0, ..., 3.6.1] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.3.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.7-p1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.7-p1].
- Root composer.json requires magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework ^3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[3.0.0, ..., 3.12.0]

Please any help,
Thanks

The error message explains the issue. The magento/data-migration-tool module you have installed requires version 1 of the monolog/monolog module, but Magento 2.4.7-p1 requires version 2 of the monolog/monolog module.
You can't have two different versions of the monolog/monolog module installed at the same time. You will either need to uninstall the magento/data-migration-tool tool or upgrade it to a version that is compatible with monolog/monolog version 2.

Update: it looks you removed the magento/data-migration-tool module. But now you are trying to run composer install using the wrong version of PHP. 2.4.7-p1 only supports PHP versions 8.2 and 8.3, you are trying to use PHP 7.1 which is no longer compatible: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements

I used this composer.json and my problem was solved
{
"name": "magento/project-community-edition",
"description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
"type": "project",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"config": {
    "allow-plugins": {
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
        "laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin": true,
        "magento/*": true,
        "php-http/discovery": true
    },
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
},
"version": "2.4.7-p1",
"require": {
    "magento/composer-dependency-version-audit-plugin": "~0.1",
    "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "^2.0.4",
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.7-p1",
    "mageplaza/module-core": "^1.5"
},
"autoload": {
    "exclude-from-classmap": [
        "**/dev/**",
        "**/update/**",
        "**/Test/**"
    ],
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ],
    "psr-0": {
        "": [
            "app/code/",
            "generated/code/"
        ]
    },
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/"
    }
},
"require-dev": {
    "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "^2",
    "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7 || ^1.0",
    "dg/bypass-finals": "^1.4",
    "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^3.22",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "^0.8",
    "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
    "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^4.7",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "^2.10",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.12",
    "phpstan/phpstan": "^1.9",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "^6.0",
    "symfony/finder": "^6.4"
},
"conflict": {
    "gene/bluefoot": "*"
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\PhpStan\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/PhpStan/",
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"prefer-stable": true,
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    }
],
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override"
}

}

Try with this code, backup your composer.josn and composer.lock file.
and create composer.json file using below code.
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
            "laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin": true,
            "magento/*": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        },
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "version": "2.4.7-p1",
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.7-p1",
        "magento/composer-dependency-version-audit-plugin": "~0.1",
        "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "^2.0.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "^2",
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7 || ^1.0",
        "dg/bypass-finals": "^1.4",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^3.22",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "^0.8",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^4.7",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "^2.10",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.12",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^1.9",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "^6.0",
        "symfony/finder": "^6.4"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "gene/bluefoot": "*"
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\PhpStan\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/PhpStan/",
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}


Please update this value in composer.json file and run composer update
 "require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "^2",
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7 || ^1.0",
        "dg/bypass-finals": "^1.4",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^3.22",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "^0.8",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^4.7",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "^2.10",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.12",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^1.9",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "^6.0"
    },


not work and this error show `"Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.7-p1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.7-p1].
- Root composer.json requires magento/composer-root-update-plugin ~1.1 -> satisfiable by magento/composer-root-update-plugin[1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2].
- friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer[v3.22.0, ..., v3.60.0] require composer/xdebug-handler ^3.0.3 -> satisfiable by composer/xdebug-handler[3.0.3, 3.0.4, 3.0.5].
- Conclusion: don't installcomposer/xdebug-handler 3.0.5 (conflict analysis result)
- Root composer.json requires'

Could you please add your composer.json file so that I can review the specific modules it contains?
